# Angular directive removes original attribute from element

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular-directive

When adding a directive on some element (e.g. `img`), and if that directive has some attribute from it as `@Input()` (e.g. `src`), original attribute will be change with `ng-reflect-*` (e.g. `ng-reflect-src`) and image will never be shown, since there is no `src` attribute.

It will only happen if it's `src` has to be evaluated, does not happen on fixed urls!

Is this expected behavior or is it bug? Is it possible to make it work? (At the moment I am workarounding it by using `src` and `source` and having as input for the directive only `source`.)

Example can be seen on following plnkr (two images should be shown but there is only one): https://plnkr.co/edit/5AjZPeyEfd6IOqxQp3kq?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that is intended behavior.

Possible workaround could be as follows

```
@HostBinding() @Input() src: string;
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/EMtAu9nc99l9OPaOzRIp?p=preview)**

Comment: You're right, that does work, and there is perhaps even better way (provided here https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17138) using `constructor(@Attribute('src') src: string) {}`

Comment: One more question, why does it consume src only when it has evaluated value (i.e. src="{{imgUrl}}") but not when it is hardcoded value (i.e. src="http://some-pic.com/link123")?